# Is there a way to do fade in scroll animations by using CSS or HTML only and no Javascript?

Tags: html, css, web

I want to have my website where whenever someone scrolls down, a picture or text will fade in up. I´ve been trying to find a way to accomplish this only using CSS or HTML as my website creator doesn't use any other language besides CSS or HTML. Is there some code that I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: As far as I know, you still need JavaScript to do this. Checkout the Intersection Observer API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API. There is also a great video on the topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUjBvuUdkhg

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. It's a lot easier with JQuery, but CSS will still work.

```
<text id="my-text">I hope this helps</text>

<style>
    #my-text {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 2s;
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
</style>
```

I hope this helps! This would work with images and text.

Test this: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GCR2PD73HDF7